# Как проверить HTTP-запрос типа POST, если серверного скрипта пока нет?

Tags: post

Есть форма HTML типа

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
<input ...>
<input ...>
<button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

При нажатии на кнопку наблюдаю в девтулзах (на вкладке "Сеть") отправление запроса типа GET (!).

Прошу помочь разобраться - почему.
И - есть ли способ посмотреть тело запроса типа POST, не имея серверного скрипта.
Предполагаю, что всё дело в значении атрибута "action", но - повторюсь - бэкенда пока нет. А запрос проверить очень нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Апач при POST-запросе на URL папки без конечного слеша, перенаправляет на URL со слешем и при этом запрос трансформируется в GET. Если же слеш поставить, то эффект пропадает.

Вывод: В action формы ставьте всегда слеш в конце URL папки, а лучше используйте URL файла.

взято от сюда [клик](https://habr.com/ru/post/55403/)

Comment: Да, я это читал, спасибо. Проблема в том, что скрипта, принимающего запрос, у меня нет. Можно ли как-то без скрипта добится, чтобы "POST" был именно "POST"? Может фиктивные или тренировочные сервера есть какие-нибудь? Чей адрес я мог бы просто для эксперимента поставить?

Comment: я не совсем понимаю для чего это ) но что мешает написать обработчик ?

Answer (score 1):

Помог так называемый [Simple HTTP Request & Response Service](https://httpbin.org)

Для проверки своего запроса типа POST достаточно в сооветствующей форме с методом POST указать атрибут
action="https://httpbin.org/post"

Тогда при отправке запроса указанный сайт вернёт всё его содержимое.